# Plotting values instead of sums in a pivot chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have this pivot table:

[image]

The data is arranged according to the following hierarchy:

Line -> Machine -> Year -> Week (1 to 52)

For each week there is a value for Score (%), Execution (%), Duration (%), Sample Quality (a number from 0 to 4).

I want to create a pivot chart that plots trends from week to week for each machine. So it would plot score from week 51 2017 to week 2 2018. I would like the trends for Score, Execution, Duration, Sample Quality.

Here is the pivot chart I get from Excel.

[image]

The lines are for the averages instead of the actual values. How do I make the chart plot the values.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the Chart/Pivot and Select **Show Field List**

Then on the right hand side of your page look for the **Values** section, as in below.

[image]

Click on the little downward facing arrow and select **Value Field Settings** to prompt the below options.

[image]

Here you can then select **SUM**, rather than **AVERAGE**.